# jupyterhub page not found 404

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am constantly receiving :

```
404 : Not Found
You are requesting a page that does not exist!
```

wheneever I open jupyterhub exposed at 0.0.0.0:8090 say on an EC2 Instance

I know somewhere it has to be a fine setting of :
c.Spawner.cmd
and c.Spawner.default_user

If I try jupyter-hublab, it works, but it is not loading my jupyterlab plugins.
And I get the above 404 errors whenever I do jupyter-lab as Spawner.cmd

And the errors I get :

```
[W 2020-07-15 09:52:17.296 JupyterHub log:174] 404 GET /hub/static/components/es6-promise/promise.min.js?v=f004a16cb856e0ff11781d01ec5ca8fe (@::ffff:10.195.84.91) 0.67ms
[W 2020-07-15 09:52:17.306 JupyterHub log:174] 404 GET /hub/static/components/react/react.production.min.js?v=34f96ffc962a7deecc83037ccb582b58 (@::ffff:10.195.84.91) 0.86ms
[I 2020-07-15 09:52:17.310 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /static/base/images/logo.png?v=641991992878ee24c6f3826e81054a0f -> /hub/static/base/images/logo.png?v=641991992878ee24c6f3826e81054a0f (@::ffff:10.195.84.91) 0.91ms
[W 2020-07-15 09:52:17.536 JupyterHub log:174] 404 GET /hub/static/components/react/react-dom.production.min.js?v=b14d91fb641317cda38dbc9dbf985ab4 (@::ffff:10.195.84.91) 1.31ms
[W 2020-07-15 09:52:17.540 JupyterHub log:174] 404 GET /hub/static/components/create-react-class/index.js?v=94feb9971ce6d26211729abc43f96cd2 (@::ffff:10.195.84.91) 0.80ms
[W 2020-07-15 09:52:17.575 JupyterHub log:174] 404 GET /hub/static/base/images/logo.png?v=641991992878ee24c6f3826e81054a0f (@::ffff:10.195.84.91) 0.80ms
[I 2020-07-15 09:52:17.821 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=20200715095212 -> /hub/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=20200715095212 (@::ffff:10.195.84.91) 0.88ms
[W 2020-07-15 09:52:18.086 JupyterHub log:174] 404 GET /hub/static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=20200715095212 (@::ffff:10.195.84.91) 0.83ms
```